# Intellij problems with writing ASCII characters on Dell Latitude Laptops

Tags: intellij-idea

I was using Intellij on my Dell Latitude E 7470. It's the smaller laptop without a special numeric keyboard. When you want to use asci code, you must press fn + alt + the number combination representing the asci on keys jkluiop... It was working just fine but I reinstalled Win some time ago and now when I press for example fn +alt + 123 to write curly braces, it automatically jumps to the bottom of the class declaration and creates the curly braces there and not at the spot where I'm writing them... Thanks for any kind of help.

This is how the keyboard looks 
[keyboard layout](https://vjauj58549.i.lithium.com/community/s/legacyfs/online/en/communityserver.discussions.components.files/3518/8461.snip1.PNG)

**Update - solution**

I figured it out. The fn + fn key 1 was end, fn 2 was down and fn 3 was bound as page down. When combined with alt it was using predefined IntelliJ shortcuts I had to remove. This functionality is probably caused by the newest Bios version of Dell Latitude laptops in version 20 + ... I personally have latitude E7470 but I have read on different forums other users complaining about incorrect workings of fn key and inability to change them because the system or Bios settings for FN keys were all removed.